# Evaluation order in ternary operator with increments

Tags: c, conditional-operator

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b) ? (a) : (b))
   int main(void) {
   int a=2;
   int b=3;

   int c = MAX(a++,b++); // c=((a++)>(b++) ? (a++) : (b++));
   printf("\na= %d", a);// a=3
   printf("\nb= %d", b);//b=5
   printf("\nc= %d", c);//c=4

   a=3;
   b=2;
   cc = MAX(a++,b++); // c=((a++)>(b++) ? (a++) : (b++));

   printf("\na= %d", a); // a=5
   printf("\nb= %d", b); //b=3
   printf("\nc= %d", c); //c=4

return 0;
}
```

I would like to know why `c` is not evaluating to 5.

It appears to me the evaluation order should be:

1. First both a and be get incremented in  `(a++)>(b++)`
2. If for example the first one is greater, the ternary operator in
   `c=((a++)>(b++) ? (a++) : (b++))`, goes to  `(a++)`, so `a`
   increments again.
3. The result of the ternary expression, which is a twice-increment,
   should be assigned to `c`, then `c` should have the greater value
   twice-incremented, that is 5. However, I am getting 4. I suspect the
   greater value's second increment is happening at the end, but I can't
   explain why, since the parentheses seem to indicate that the
   assignment comes at the end.

Any idea?

Comment: The postfix ++ operator returns the value before and increments the variable. Try using the prefix ++ operator `++a` to get 5.

Comment: Please note, that using such a macro with such a parameters is considered a criminal offence in some countries.

Comment: A macro is not a function, as has to be frequently said.

Comment: Re “the parentheses seem to indicate that the assigment comes at the end”: Parentheses have no effect on side effect. The effect of `++` incrementing an object is a *side effect*. It is generally separate from the evaluation of the expression and is not affected by parentheses. (It may be affected by sequence points and other ordering rules in the expression.)

Comment: unrelated suggestion: prefer printing `"\n"` at the end of printf, ie: `printf("%d%s%f\n", ...)` rather than `printf("\n%d%s%f", ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postfix `++` operator has a *result* and a *side effect*.  The *result* of `a++` is the value of `a` before the increment - given

```
int a = 1;
int x = a++;
```

the value of `x` will be `1` and the value of `a` will be 2.  Note that the side effect of adding `1` to `a` does not have to be applied immediately after evaluation - it only has to be applied before the next sequence point.

So, looking at

```
((a++) > (b++)) ? (a++) : (b++)
```

The `?:` operator forces left-to-right evaluation, so the first thing that happens is that `(a++) > (b++)` is evaluated<sup>1</sup>.  Since `a` is initially `2` and `b` is initially `3`, the result of the expression is false (`0`).  The `?` operator introduces a sequence point, so the *side effects* to `a` and `b` are applied and `a` is now `3` and `b` is now `4`.

Since the result of the condition expression was `0`, we evaluate `b++`.  Same thing, the *result* of the expression is the current value of `b` (`4`), and that value gets assigned to `c`.  The side effect to `b` is applied at some point, and by the time everything's finished, `a` is `3`, `b` is `5`, and `c` is `4`.

---

1. Although within that expression either `a++` or `b++` may be evaluated first, since the `>` operator doesn't force left-to-right evaluation.

Comment: How do I know where sequence points are located in a generic expression?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: See Annex C of the [C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  This is not the *official* standard, but it's close enough for this.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider for example this declaration

```
int c = MAX(a++,b++);
```

after the macro substitution there will be

```
int c = (( a++) >( b++ ) ? (a++) : (b++));
```

The variables `a` and `b` are initialized like

```
int a=2;
int b=3;
```

As `a` is less than `b` then the third expression `(b++)` will be evaluated as a result of the conditional operator. In the first expression `( a++) >( b++ )` `a` and `b` were incremented. There is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first expression.

So `a` will be set to `3`, `b` will be set to `4`.

As it was already said the value of the conditional operator is the value of the third expression `(b++)` where there is used the post-increment. The value of the post-increment operator is the value of its operand before incrementing.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the
>   operand.** As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
>   incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
>   it).

So the value of the conditional operator is `4`. This value will be assigned to the variable `c`. But as a side effect the value of `b` will be incremented.

Thus after this declaration `a` will be equal to `3`, `b` will be equal to `5` and `c` will be equal to `4`.

For clarity this declaration

```
int c = (( a++) >( b++ ) ? (a++) : (b++));
```

in fact can be rewritten in the logically equivalent way.

```
int result = a > b;
++a;
++b;

int c;

if ( result != 0 )
{
    c = a++;
}
else
{
    c = b++;
}
```

Comment: Ok if in post-increments the actual increment is just a side effect happening at the end, then shouldn't the whole expression be analized as if there were no increments at all and only at the very end execute the pending increments on the values "touched" by the evaluation flow, that is, the two increments of the first expression of the ternary operation and the second increment on the second or third expression? Doing so, for a=2 and b=3 would result on c=3, and  at the very end a=2+1=3 and b=3+2=5.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver As I wrote after the evaluation of the first expression there is a sequence point that is the corresponding side effects for the variables a and be will be applied.  As the first expression evaluates to logical false then the value of the conditional operator is the value of the third expression where there is used the post-increment. So the the value is the value of its operand before incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

For a++ it's equivalent as saying

```
int temp = a;
a = a + 1;
return temp;
```

so in the case of a=2, b=3, we can go to the condition (a++)>(b++) and we can have a rewritten as

```
int temp1 = a;
a = a + 1;
return temp1;
```

and b rewritten as

```
int temp2 = b;
b = b + 1;
return temp2;
```

now since it's only a conditional statement, we're really just evaluating the old values of a and b before the increment which is temp1 = 2 and temp2 = 3 while at the same time a and b values have changed a = 3, b = 4. Since temp1 < temp2 from the old value, we go to the false clause of the ternary operator (b++) and do the same thing as we did before

```
int temp3 = b;
b = b + 1;
return temp3;
```

so now b is 5 while the returned temp3 is the previous value of b which is 4. Hope this helps!